# Many .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to make these rewrite rules in .htaccess?

```
www.mysite.com/123 -> www.mysite.com/project.php?id=123
www.mysite.com/123/ -> www.mysite.com/project.php?id=123
www.mysite.com/about -> www.mysite.com/about/
www.mysite.com/about/ -> www.mysite.com/about/
www.mysite.com/123.php -> www.mysite.com/123.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /project.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```